# Puzzle - How to 'colorify' part of an image from PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, css, image

I want to have a map (which is image-mapped) show green in areas where some criteria applies, yellow in some other areas and red in other areas.
[image: Possible sample map]

The goal is to display a clickable image which will will colour certain states which match certain criteria. I was previously considering flash but the owner simply doesn't want flash. One possible alternative would be to display 'clickable' coloured labels on the map but I don't know how to do this either. Does anyone know how I can solve this? Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: search for image map generator, pretty easy to generate. (i am not sure for the coloring part, but to make it clickable)

Comment: @DanLee: Thanks, the image is already mapped (not completely yet thought), the puzzle is with the color on criteria part...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is what I finally did.

- I found an svg map of Nigeria on wikipedia (which has the svg maps of
  almost every country).
- I downloaded [InkScape](http://inkscape.org/download/?lang=en) and cut out the parts I didn't need from
  the map.
- I used the [Raphael SVG to HTML Converter tool](http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/SVGTOHTML_LIVE90.php) to convert it to
  code usable by raphael.
- From here it was quite very easy, I could use path.fill to 'colorify'
  the image and it was easy to set different functions for clicking any
  part. Scaling was also not an issue as the image could be scaled
  dynamically based on the container.

Thanks to everyone especially [Olle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11181558/puzzle-how-to-colorify-part-of-an-image-from-php/11181615#11181615) for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

Check out Raphael: http://raphaeljs.com/

Comment: nice tool, the glow function would have been nice, but won't be of much use in this case...

Answer (score 1):

jQuery Vector Map http://jqvmap.com/

or

[JVectorMap](http://jvectormap.com/)

JVectorMap comes with more pre-generated maps than jqvmap. But you should be able to generate your own.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at jQuery. PHP is not where you will do this, its going to be client side Javascript to manipulate an html image map using either overlay images or a change in CSS via the Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth, this can be done in php using the gd extensions.  Essentially what you do is load an all white version of the image, and then using coordinates on the image, fill the image with a given color using imagefilltoborder (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilltoborder.php) .

However, to make it clickable, you would need to use an image map or javascript on the clientside anyway.