# Is there any tool that can convert line drawings to path matrices?

Tags: javascript, ide, drawing

This is a follow up of this question: [Puzzle - How to 'colorify' part of an image from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11181558/puzzle-how-to-colorify-part-of-an-image-from-php)

Basically I want to create an interactive map that will colorify certain areas based on certain conditions. I have been able to find a tool called [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/). However I am completely lost on how I can generate path matrices with it. An example of a path for Victoria in the [Australia map demo](http://raphaeljs.com/australia.html) looks like:

```
aus.vic = R.path("M252.869,203.121l-0.873-0.643l-1.721-0.121l-8.182-4.065l0.178-1.349l-0.354-1.082l-0.722-1.028l-0.566-1.235l0.204-1.168l-1.433-0.73l-0.899,0.326l-0.711,0.295l-0.74,0.111l-1.083,0.354l-1.451,0.408l-1.961-0.461l-1.037-0.603l-0.896,0.327l-0.658,0.666l-1.164-0.204l-1.223-0.571l-0.925,0.139l-1.434-0.729l-1.85,0.28l-0.823-0.444l-0.741,0.11l-0.471,0.638l0.223,1.481l-1.295,0.195l-1.619-0.701l-1.277-0.943l-0.379-1.268l-1.973-1.783l-1.619-0.701l-1.138-0.018l-1.444-2.054l-0.604-2.748l-1.008-0.413l-1.721-0.119l-0.98-0.232l-1.055,0.539l-0.045,0.953l-1.092-0.971l-0.492-2.009l-1.73-1.44l-2.12-0.248l-1.748-0.305l-1.024,0.723l-1.834-0.86l-1.109,0.168l-0.08,0.038v28.152l0.436,0.031l2.342,1.916v1.065l0.64-0.214l0.638,0.427l1.278-1.491l2.556,1.278l1.703-0.427l7.881,4.261l3.193-3.195l2.557-1.704h1.49l0.428-1.275l-1.492,0.425l-0.853-0.64h1.063l2.771-2.129l1.277,2.555l-1.277,1.703l-1.917-0.424l1.917,1.702l1.277-0.852l0.64,0.213l0.211-1.703h1.492l0.426,1.276l-0.852,0.214l-0.215,1.276l1.49,1.065l1.491-0.213l0.214,0.426l-0.639-0.213l1.064,1.916l0.851-0.64l0.853,0.427l-0.213-0.64l0.854,1.705l1.064,1.063l0.426-2.769l-1.277,0.852l-0.426-1.703h2.13l2.526-0.843l4.074-4.269l2.768-1.703l-3.406,1.489l1.917-1.278l-0.071-0.07l-0.568-0.567l1.492,0.427l1.703-0.64l-0.213,0.427l9.371-0.853l1.915-1.703l-0.638-0.64H252.869z")
```

Does anyone know any tool that can do this or even something similar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a bit of research, I found this handy little tutorial:

http://playground.mobily.pl/tutorials/building-an-interactive-map-with-raphael.html

They were able to find an SVG of the map they wanted on wikipedia and just pull the path info from that. If you are unable to find an SVG of the map you're looking to colorize, use an application that will create an SVG and just make it yourself - Adobe Illustrator, Inkscape, so on.

Comment: Wow, that was a great answer, so I was actually looking for an SVG Editor but I didn't know what it was called. Thanks!